# Use Query Result Row in Another Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to use the row from a query in another query.

This query correctly displays the username of the user currently signed in:

```
$param = $fgmembersite->UserEmail();

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM Users1 WHERE email = '$param'
");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
echo $row['username'] ;
    }
```

I'm trying to find a way to use $row['username'] in another query something like...

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = '" . $row['username'] . "' ");
```

This doesn't give me a coding error, but it doesn't work. The username row obviously can't be taken from a separate query the way I'm attempting.

I have tried every combination I can think of but nothing has worked for me. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user in (SELECT username FROM Users1 WHERE email = '$param')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the queries into one:

```
SELECT `messages`.*
FROM `messages`
    JOIN `Users1`
        ON `Users1`.`username`=`messages`.`to_user`
WHERE
    `Users1`.`email`='$param'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you should place your second query inside while:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  echo $row['username'] ;
  $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = 
    '" . $row['username'] . "' ");
}
```

Now loop ends when mysqli_fetch_arrray returns NULL and that NULL you are trying to insert into second query.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two queries into one.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = (SELECT username FROM Users1 WHERE email = '$param')
```